# ESP32 using Arduino: Internal Pull-ups don't work on GPIO25 or GPIO32

Tags: arduino, adc, gpio, pullup, esp32

I'm programming a custom ESP32 board using Arduino where GPIO25 and GPIO32 are connected to pogo pins via short 5mm traces and to nothing else. The goal is to poll for a short between them as part of an alignment procedure - pretty straightforward.

The issue is, pinMode(X, INPUT_PULLUP) does not actaully turn on the pullup for either pin; the ADC readings are always floating. Whichever pin I'm using still successfully detects a short when intended, but because It is floating and never pulled high, it causes a lot of false flags.  Code below:

```
    int foo=9999;
    pinMode(25, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(32,INPUT_PULLUP);
    while(foo>0){
        foo=analogRead(32);
        Serial.println(foo);
        //do other stuff
    }
```

Comment: I typed the code in here directly, that was a typo. Fixed now. I'm reading the correct ADC pin when the described problem happens

Comment: This Reddit thread has that IDF library direct approach that may work. I'm about to try it out myself. [Reddit Thread on ADC w/ internal pullup](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/c493it/adc_input_w_internal_pullup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I got to the bottom of this for anyone googling:

Using analogRead attaches the GPIO pin you're using to the ADC channel and disconnects it from the pull-up. Calling pinMode(X, INPUT_PULLUP) after every analogRead will reinstate the bias.

Comment: Would that actually cause the pullup to be active during the ADC sampling?   Or does this just mean you end up relying on stray capacitance to hold the value?

Comment: The latter it seems, which is good enough for me as a workaround. I no longer get any false positives with this method. I'd bet there's a way to achieve both using IDF library functions directly.

Comment: If it's really capacitance making it happen, I'd be tempted to add my own capacitors.  Or external resistors, unless that causes a power consumption issue...